# js/react: sync call in event handler works, but async call does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In Visual Studio 2019 Ive used the "Asp net Core +React" project template. In this the AuthorizeService is included, which supports subscription on events, like user has logged in/out.

The sample code is using React class-approach and use the subscription in the included LoginMenu.js

```
componentDidMount() {
   this._subscription = authService.subscribe(() => this.populateState());
   this.populateState();
}

async populateState() {
     const [isAuthenticated, user] = await Promise.all([authService.isAuthenticated(), 
     authService.getUser()])
            this.setState({
                isAuthenticated,
                userName: user && user.name
            });
        }
```

This is all good. Now, I want to use subscribe in my method, and if authenticated I want to load my ApplicationUser from my WebApi (using React funcational approach)

This does not work, it gives A LOT of repeated calls to Communication.get and also "failed to fetch"-exception during fetch-call.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const populateUser = async () => {
        var isAuth2 = await authService.isAuthenticated();
        var token = await authService.getAccessToken();
              
        if (isAuth2 && token) {                 
            const userTmp = await Communication.get('/users/getCurrentUser');           
            dispatch(setUser(userTmp));
        }
    };
    if (!hasSubscribed) {
        setHasSubscribed(true);
        authService.subscribe(() => populateUser());
    }
    populateUser();

}, [hasSubscribed])
```

Communication.get():
get:

```
async function (url) {
 
    var token = await authService.getAccessToken();
    let response = {};
    try {
        response = await fetch(url,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: new Headers({

                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                })
            }
        )
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Exception in call to  " + url +": "+ e);
    }

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error(`Server error (get). (${response.status}) for url ${url}`);
    }

    
    return await response.json();
},
```

However, if I call my service **synchronous** it all works well.

So, what Im I missing? Why does async calls result in wierd behaviour?

Comment: Where and how is `isAuth` variable that is passed as dependency to useEffect defined

Comment: sorry, thats a rest from old code, Iv removed it. It was never set in the example (before and after editing it away).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the call to `populateUser()` inside the `if` statement:

```
if (!hasSubscribed) {
   setHasSubscribed(true);
   authService.subscribe(() => populateUser());
   populateUser()
}
```

you should also probably return a cleanup function from the effect to unsubscribe.